# SharePoint server : how to set up a word template with SharePoint version number in a content type set in a content type hub

Tags: sharepoint-server, word, template, content-type-hub, version

I explain : we use content type hub to spread content types in all SharePoint sites. In the content type hub we have a template library, where we configure the templates with quick parts, and we would like to use the SharePoint version value. It can be done using labels and policies... problem is when we copy a document from the library template into another libray, the document version quick part is not updated.
Looking into the word document XML, it seems that for each library the link between the quick part and the hidden version property is different. Has anyone a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, find myself a solution. Activating labels on all libraries, and using C# server code to "repair" the Word document. The Version label is incorrect once document is moved between site collections, so the code has to repair it... If only content type hub team and Word team talked together...